# How do i keep the same background color after my background fades in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, background, fade

i am a beginner and i was making a game where i needed the background to fade. The program i wrote makes the background fade but it does not keep the color it just faded into because it jumps right back to the color it was after some time. I wanted it also keep the color it faded into at a certain time, for example i want the program to fade when the time is 20,000 milliseconds into the game, instead of pressing the MOUSEBUTTONDOWN key, that is why i wrote 'print(pygame.time.get_ticks()) but i am having trouble using it, if there is another way, please comment it for me to see. Thanks!

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()

DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 700
DISPLAY_WIDTH = 900

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

#colors
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
SKY_BLUE = (102,178,255)


def fade(width, height):
    fade = pygame.Surface((width, height))
    fade.fill((31,97,141))
    for alpha in range(0, 300):
        fade.set_alpha(alpha)
        screen.blit(fade, (0,0))
        pygame.display.update()
        print(pygame.time.get_ticks())
        screen.fill((31,97,141))

running = True
while running:
    screen.fill(SKY_BLUE)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            fade(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT)

    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: First question: You're pausing the main loop to fade the screen. Is this what you want? Or do you want to fade in the main loop (while the game plays)?

Comment: No, the function that fades the background is called fade() and i have put it into the mainloop with a if statement. But when you run the program the background fades but goes back to its original color after some random period of time. What i want is for it to keep the color it faded into, i don't care wether it be in the mainloop or a totally different function. I just want to know how to do it.

Comment: maybe instead of `fill(SKY_BLUE)` you should use `Surface` with this color and later you can assign faded surface in varialbe which keep sufrace with `SKY_BLUE` color.

Comment: or maybe after fading you should assign this color to variable `SKY_BLUE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fade the background and maintain it, you will need to create a shared surface accessible by the fade function and the main loop. In the main, check the counter and run the fade process. This will pause the main loop for the fade. After the fade is complete, check the fade surface variable and blit it if it is set.

Here is the updated code:

```
fade = None  # before fade process

def dofade(width, height):
    global fade  # share variable with main loop
    fade = pygame.Surface((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))
    fade.fill((31,97,141))
    for alpha in range(0, 300):
        fade.set_alpha(alpha)
        screen.blit(fade, (0,0))
        pygame.display.update()
        #print(pygame.time.get_ticks())
        clock.tick(FPS)
        #screen.fill((31,97,141))

running = True
while running:
    screen.fill(SKY_BLUE)  # initial color
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:  # can start fade early
            dofade(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT)
            
    tks = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if (tks >= 20000 and not fade): # if hit counter and fade not processed yet
        dofade(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT)  # loop paused for fade process
    if fade: # if fade process done
        screen.blit(fade, (0,0)) # always show fade surface

    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply assign new color to variable `SKY_BLUE` and it will use it all time

```
def fade(width, height):
    global SKY_BLUE
    
    # ... your code ...

    print('after fade')

    SKY_BLUE = (31,97,141)
```

---

My version with other changes

```
import pygame

# --- constants ---

DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 700
DISPLAY_WIDTH = 900

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
SKY_BLUE = (102,178,255)

FPS = 60

# --- functions ---

def fade(width, height):
    global SKY_BLUE
    
    fade = pygame.Surface((width, height))
    fade.fill((31,97,141))

    for alpha in range(0, 256):
        fade.set_alpha(alpha)

        screen.blit(fade, (0,0))

        clock.tick(FPS)

        pygame.display.update()

    print('after fade')

    SKY_BLUE = (31,97,141)
    
# --- main ---

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
running = True
while running:
    screen.fill(SKY_BLUE)
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            fade(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT)

    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.update()

# - end -

pygame.quit()
```

---

In the same way you can use also surface.

First use surface with color `SKY_BLUE`

```
background = pygame.Surface((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))
background.fill(SKY_BLUE)

running = True
while running:

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
```

and after fading replace it

```
def fade(width, height):
    global background
    
    # ... code ... 

    print('after fade')

    background = fade
```

**BTW:** In this place it would be good to use different name for surface `fade` and function `fade()` because it can me misleading.

---

```
import pygame

# --- constants ---

DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 700
DISPLAY_WIDTH = 900

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
SKY_BLUE = (102,178,255)

FPS = 60

# --- functions ---

def fade(width, height):
    global background
    
    surface = pygame.Surface((width, height))
    surface.fill((31,97,141))

    for alpha in range(0, 256):
        surface.set_alpha(alpha)

        screen.blit(surface, (0,0))

        clock.tick(FPS)

        pygame.display.update()

    print('after fade')

    background = surface
    
# --- main ---

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
background = pygame.Surface((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))
background.fill(SKY_BLUE)

running = True
while running:

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            fade(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT)

    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.update()

# - end -

pygame.quit()
```

---

As for fading after 20 000 milliseconds you can use `pygame.time.get_ticks()` to get current time and calculate when to start fading (`start_fading`) and later in loop get again current time and compare with `start_fading` to start fading.

It may need boolead variable (`True/False`) to not do it again after first fading.

```
current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
start_fading = current_time + 20000
faded = False

running = True
while running:

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        #elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        #    fade(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT)

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    
    if not faded and current_time >= start_fading:
        fade(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT)
        faded = True
        
    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.update()
```

---

If you want to repeate fading then don't use `faded` but chagen `start_fading` after fading

```
    if current_time >= start_fading:
        fade(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT)
        start_fading = current_time + 20000
```

If you want more elements runs with delays then you could keep them on list and use `for`-loop and after running some function you can remove them from this list. But I will not use it here.

```
import pygame

# --- constants ---

DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 700
DISPLAY_WIDTH = 900

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
SKY_BLUE = (102,178,255)

FPS = 60

# --- functions ---

def fade(width, height):
    global background
    
    surface = pygame.Surface((width, height))
    surface.fill((31,97,141))

    for alpha in range(0, 256):
        surface.set_alpha(alpha)

        screen.blit(surface, (0,0))

        clock.tick(FPS)

        pygame.display.update()

    print('after fade')

    background = surface
    
# --- main ---

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
background = pygame.Surface((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))
background.fill(SKY_BLUE)

current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
start_fading = current_time + 20000
faded = False

running = True
while running:

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        #elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        #    fade(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT)

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    
    if not faded and current_time >= start_fading:
        fade(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT)
        faded = True
        
    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.update()

# - end -

pygame.quit()
```

---

There is also other method - you can use [pygame.time.set_timer()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer()) with `pygame.USEREVENT` to generate custom event with some delay

```
FADE_EVENT = pygame.USEREVENT

pygame.time.set_timer(FADE_EVENT, 2000)
```

and then you can use `for event in pygame.event.get():` to catch it and execute `fade()`

```
        if event.type == FADE_EVENT:
            pygame.time.set_timer(FADE_EVENT, 0) # turn off after one use 
            fade(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT)
```

---

```
import pygame

# --- constants ---

DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 700
DISPLAY_WIDTH = 900

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
SKY_BLUE = (102,178,255)

FPS = 60

# --- functions ---

def fade(width, height):
    global background
    
    surface = pygame.Surface((width, height))
    surface.fill((31,97,141))

    for alpha in range(0, 256):
        surface.set_alpha(alpha)

        screen.blit(surface, (0,0))

        clock.tick(FPS)

        pygame.display.update()

    print('after fade')

    background = surface
    
# --- main ---

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
background = pygame.Surface((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))
background.fill(SKY_BLUE)

#FADE_EVENT = pygame.event.custom_type()  # PyGame 2.0
FADE_EVENT = pygame.USEREVENT             # PyGame 1.9

#pygame.time.set_timer(FADE_EVENT, 2000, True) # PyGame 2.0 # `once=True` - turn off after one use
pygame.time.set_timer(FADE_EVENT, 2000)        # PyGame 1.9 # doesn't have `once`, it will need `set_timer(..., 0)`

running = True
while running:

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == FADE_EVENT:
            pygame.time.set_timer(FADE_EVENT, 0) # PyGame 1.9 # turn off after one use 
            fade(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT)
            
    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.update()

# - end -

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I added example which uses time to execute `fade()`. I also mentioned that you can use `set_timer` with custom events for this.

Comment: Do you know the reason why the program pauses for the first few seconds of the fade, what i mean by that is that the program does not even close when you try to until like 2 seconds after the fade happens.

Comment: when fade is runnig then it doesn't run `for event in pygame.event.get():` to check if you want to close it. You would need to add loop `for event in pygame.event.get():` inside `for alpha in range(0, 256):` to close it during fading. Or code would have to be more complex to do all with only one  `for event in pygame.event.get():`. Maybe for small changes in `alpha` it seems like it doesn't nothing - you could try with bigger steps ie. `for alpha in range(0, 256, 4):`